# CSS Sprite: Responsiveness formula not working

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I had another concern with sprites. Since its position is normally fixed, I want it to be responsive and after several attempts with

> spritecow
>
> sprite responsive formulas `background width / (x-coor)-(width)`
>
> http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/

I can't seem to make it work. Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nattygurl/b38gha3h/4/) of my CSS and HTML. Got sick of minimizing the window just to see if it worked. Any more suggestions that would make it possible to be responsive? or tips? Like how I could code my CSS properly with CSS sprites.

Comment: Before getting sick also, what do you expect in terms of responsiveness? Should the total image just scale?

Comment: @Gerard There added more details on jsfiddle